# Simultaneous digital and analog output on pipewire

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, realtek

i'm currently trying to configure pipewire to use both digital and analog output at the same time with different streams, like in windows.
In pavucontrol currently i have to switch between "analog duplex" and "Digital stereo (IEC958) output + analog stereo input", this is not good especially when using pulseEffect, it causes all sorts of troubles when switching.

I have an x570 aorus master with a Realtek ALC1220-VB and on majaro is using Starship/Matisse HD audio controller

Thanks.

Edit: apparently using the pro audio profile did what i wanted for the output but now the analog input doesn't work: the two neither one of the two interfaces can retrieve any sound from the mic and the first one it doesn't have volume meter bar.

Answer (score 1):

Open `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/profile-sets/default.conf`, and add this to it:

```
[Profile output:analog-stereo+output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo]
description = Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Duplex
output-mappings = analog-stereo iec958-stereo
input-mappings = analog-stereo
```

PulseAudio Profiles work with Pipewire now.

Works with my Soundblaster Z

Comment: The config file is on Arch Linux now located here: `/usr/share/alsa-card-profile/mixer/profile-sets/default.conf` -- Your solution works for my ASUS TUF X570-PLUS with Realtek S1200A. It makes both outputs available as separate sinks (and they can both output different audio).