# Simultaneous input and output on pipewire for USB-C microphone

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, pipewire

I have an `Elgato Wave 3`, and I am trying to use it on Ubuntu 22.04 with PipeWire (had to replace PulseAudio because my Sony WH-1000XM5 was not able to give me high-quality audio without replacing it with PipeWire).

The issue I am facing is that, when I connect the microphone, it shows the following inputs/outputs:

- Analog Stereo Output
- Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output
- Mono Input
- Pro Audio
- Off

I cannot make it have input + output at the same time, it can only be in input mode or output mode at once...

After digging a lot on the internet, I found some related stuff, for example, creating or updating a `udev` conf file when I connect the microphone or the computer starts, but I cannot make it use input + output at the same time.

One example is this file I have copy-pasted and edited:

```
[General]
auto-profiles = no 

[Mapping analog-stereo-input]
device-strings = hw:%f
channel-map = left,right
paths-input = analog-input-mic analog-input
direction = input
priority = 4 

[Mapping analog-mono]
device-strings = hw:%f
channel-map = mono
paths-input = analog-input-mic analog-input
direction = input
priority = 3 

[Mapping analog-mono-left]
device-strings = hw:%f
channel-map = mono,aux1
paths-input = analog-input-mic analog-input
direction = input
priority = 2 

[Mapping analog-mono-right]
device-strings = hw:%f
channel-map = aux1,mono
paths-input = analog-input-mic analog-input
direction = input
priority = 1 

[Mapping analog-stereo-output]
device-strings = hw:%f
channel-map = left,right
paths-output = analog-output
direction = output

[Profile output:analog-stereo-output+input:analog-mono]
description = Analog Stereo Output + Analog Mono Input
output-mappings = analog-stereo-output
input-mappings = analog-mono
```

This does not work, I tried using all `analog-mono` available there, but it never shows up, like an input is not valid or available and just does not load the profile at all, nothing shows up as connected on `PulseAudio Volume Control`.

I did try `auto-profiles = yes`, and I see the following inputs/outputs:

- Analog Stereo Output
- Analog Mono Input
- Pro Audio
- Off

I thought that having my own profile (mixing mappings) would work, but clearly does not...

I did also try using `defaul.conf` (`auto-profiles = yes`) but shows the same list as I shared at the beginning of the question.

I did try using `Pro Audio`, but I cannot make it fully work on the OS, is like I have the input and output selected, but I cannot change the volume using the normal GNOME UI, and the microphone is not detected on Chrome and other apps, but I do have audio output...

I did try this answer but did not work, same issue: [Simultaneous digital and analog output on pipewire](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/655767/simultaneous-digital-and-analog-output-on-pipewire)

Comment: Why would you want output on a microphone?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider see that [it has a 3.5 jack](https://www.elgato.com/us/en/p/wave-3-black), so you can pass audio through it, more convenient when you want to hear yourself, and, in my case, I have 2 computers, so I do not have to disconnect and connect an audio jack nor have 2 headsets, I just push the button on the KVM and switch microphone and audio at the same time, super convenient